# How to open HTML file having another extension in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

I have a HTML file and I need to display it in `JTextPane`.

```
editor.setPage("file:///" + new File("test-resources/test.html").getAbsoluteFile());
```

This works properly. It uses my modified HTML editor kit and displays special tags as needed. But modified file is not exactly HTML. It should have another extension. But that's a problem.

```
editor.setPage("file:///" + new File("test-resources/test.xhtbm").getAbsoluteFile());
```

The file has been just renamed and is being displayed as plain text now. Is there some way to force `JTextPane` to open HTML file with extension XHTBM as HTML file? Am I forced to use HTML extension if using `JTextPane`?

Comment: `"file:///" + new File("..").getAbsoluteFile()` use `new File("..").getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL()` instead.  The 2nd form will correctly encode space characters in the file name/path, the 1st form won't.

Comment: *"..display it in `JTextEditorPane`" BTW DYM 1) `JTextPane` 2) `JEditorPane`3) A 3rd party class. 4) You need a break. 5) something else?

Comment: no, a mere renaming wouldn't doesn't make a difference (the editor doesn't even know the _file_ name)

Comment: Renaming should not make a difference, but it does. I need to force the editor to use my modified `HTMLEditorKit` for file with extension `.xhtbm`. It only works when the file has `html` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found (see [the post JEditorPane and custom editor kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526883/jeditorpane-and-custom-editor-kit/7567419#7567419)):

```
public void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    editor.setEditorKit(new ModifiedHTMLEditorKit());
    ModifiedHTMLDocument doc = (ModifiedHTMLDocument)editor.getDocument();
    try {
        editor.getEditorKit().read(new FileReader(fileName), doc, 0);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException b) {
        throw new IOException("Could not fill data into editor.", b);
    }
}
```

This is the proper technique.

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to use a `JEditorPane` and call `JEditorPane.setContentType(String)`.

See [setContentType(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

> ..For example if the type is specified as `text/html; charset=EUC-JP` the content will be loaded using the EditorKit registered for `text/html` and the Reader provided to the EditorKit to load unicode into the document will use the `EUC-JP` charset for translating to unicode..

Comment: I've read this. But how to get the proper content type? I can my editor kit assign to `text/html`, but when I change the extension to `xhtbm`, I change the content type too.

Comment: Can you put a small `xhtbm` file on the net somewhere that we can hot-link to for testing purposes?