# JEditorPane and custom editor kit

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I've a trivial question. I need to load an existing file into `JEditorPane` using custom editor kit.
I've a editor kit, a file with some extension and I need to force the `JEditorPane` to recognize my file and use my editor kit. I've found only, that's possibile, but nowhere how.

The kit is based on HTML and the file too. If file has the `.html` extension, it works, but when I rename the file to `.xhtbm`, it is opened as plain text. The content type is set to `text/plain`, but I'm unable to register my editor kit for this type, because there is already registered another editor kit for this content type.

Actually the question is: Is really possible to associate some editor kit with some file type?

Comment: as I already mentioned in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525737/how-to-open-html-file-having-another-extension-in-in-jtextpane: the _file_ name has nothing to do with it! The problem is somewhere else ...

Comment: But it strange. If the file is test.html, it works, if file has been renamed to test.htmx, it doesn't work. (The content type is always text/plain. Event for HTML.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your EditorKit and user the kit's read() method passing the file there.

The reader used in the read method should understand how to parse the content.

Comment: Unfortunately that's impossible. You need to associate your editor kit with proper mime anyway. And then it works in the same way: you change the extension and then see plain text containing markups.

Comment: Can you paste example code, please? It does not work for me. The HTML file is loaded, but tags only consumed. The text is displayed in one blog merging content of all paragraphs and tables together.

Comment: The content type is used to get proper content from clipboard. E.g. when you copy in MS Word multiple different types are placed in clipboard (plain text, html, rtf and binary content). When you use read() method it has just one Reader which can work with specific content (the kit developed for).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Stanislav. In his example (see [the last page of article](http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_example.html), method `initEditor()`) I found the proper way. The mistake was in the order of commands. That works:

```
public void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    editor.setEditorKit(new ModifiedHTMLEditorKit());
    ModifiedHTMLDocument doc = (ModifiedHTMLDocument)editor.getDocument();
    try {
        editor.getEditorKit().read(new FileReader(fileName), doc, 0);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException b) {
        throw new IOException("Could not fill data into editor.", b);
    }
}
```

Then I call `openFile("test.xhtbm")` and all goes without friction.

Answer (score 0):

You Could:

```
static{
    // register EditorKit for plaintext content
    JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType( "text/plain", "HtmlEditorKit" );
}
```

before your:

`public static void main(String[] args){...}`

Sorry for the Late Response!