# JEditorPane, HTMLEditorKit - custom action inserting custom tag

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

I'm faithing with `JEditorPane`. I need simple editor. I've solved the problem with loading and modified HTML containing custom (two) tags (see [my older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526883/jeditorpane-and-custom-editor-kit)). It displays the document properly and I can even edit it now. I can write text, delete either characters or my custom elements. I won a battle, but haven't won the war. The next step is regrettably very problematical too. I'm unable to insert my custom tags.

I have a custom action:

```
import my.own.HTMLEditorKit; //extends standard HTMLEditorKit
import my.own.HTMLDocument; //extends standard HTMLDocument

class InsertElementAction extends StyledTextAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InsertElementAction(String actionName) {
        super(actionName);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JEditorPane editor = getEditor(e);

        if (editor == null)
            return;

        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
        HTMLEditorKit ekit = (HTMLEditorKit) editor.getEditorKit();
        int offset = editor.getSelectionStart();

        try {
            ekit.insertHTML(doc, offset, "<span>ahoj</span>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.SPAN);
            Element ele = doc.getRootElements()[0];
            ele = ele.getElement(1).getElement(0);
            doc.setInnerHTML(ele, "<bar medium=\"#DEFAULT\" type=\"packaged\" source=\"identifier\" />");
        }
        catch (BadLocationException ble) {
            throw new Error(ble);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

It workts properly. I can insert the `span` element. But I cannot insert non-standard tag in this way. I can insert just `code`, `span` and so on, but not my tag. For my tag I'm forced to use this:

```
ekit.insertHTML(doc, offset, "x<bar medium=\"#DEFAULT\" type=\"packaged\" source=\"identifier\" />x", 0, 0, null);
```

There are two critical problems

1. The custom tag must be bounded with non-whispace characters (here x)
2. The current element's body is split

When I insert `span` element into `<p>paragraph</p>`, I get `<p>par<span>ahoj</span>agraph</p>` as expected. Howerever unknown tag is allways inserted as child of `body` element and the result (e.g. for unknown tag `x`) is `<p>par</p><x>ahoj</x><p>agraph</p>`.

The work is dead exhausting. I'm faithing with this relatively simple task since weeks. I'm already wasted. If the insertion won't to work, I can scrap it all...

Comment: What object type is an `AppErrors.EDITORKIT_ACTIONFAILURE`?  If `String`, why not `throw new Throwable(AppErrors.EDITORKIT_ACTIONFAILURE, ioe);`?

Comment: It does not matter. I've the post updated to be more comprehensive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. HTMLEditorKit is used to render HTML. If you feed it with non-HTML tags, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @JB Nizet  The editor kits **can** be tweaked to support new tags.  I added support for the `applet` element (OK - that *is* an HTML 3.2 element, but it was not supported by default) into a `JEditorPane` for use in [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/).  Whether it makes much sense to do so is a separate matter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm immerged to my code too much. I've updated the post one more time to make it a bit more comprehensive than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround. The tag is inserted this way:

```
ModifiedHTMLDocument doc = (ModifiedHTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
int offset = editor.getSelectionStart();
//insert our special tag (if the tag is not bounded with non-whitespace character, nothing happens)
doc.insertHTML(offset, "-<specialTag />-");
//remove leading and trailing minuses
doc.remove(offset, 1); //at the current position is the minus before tag inserted
doc.remove(offset + 1, 1); //the next sign is minus after new tag (the tag is nowhere)
//Note: no, you really cannot do that: doc.remove(offset, 2), because then the tag is deleted
```

My `ModifiedHTMLDocument` contains a method `insertHTML()`, which calls the medhod hidden by reflection:

```
public void insertHTML(int offset, String htmlText) throws BadLocationException, IOException {
    if (getParser() == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("No HTMLEditorKit.Parser");

    Element elem = getCurrentElement(offset);

    //the method insertHTML is not visible
    try {
        Method insertHTML = javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.class.getDeclaredMethod("insertHTML",
                new Class[] {Element.class, int.class, String.class, boolean.class});
        insertHTML.setAccessible(true);
        insertHTML.invoke(this, new Object[] {elem, offset, htmlText, false});
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("The method insertHTML() could not be invoked", e);
    }
}
```

The last piece of our brick-box is a method looking for the current element:

```
public Element getCurrentElement(int offset) {
    ElementIterator ei = new ElementIterator(this);
    Element elem, currentElem = null;
    int elemLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while ((elem = ei.next()) != null) { //looking for closest element
        int start = elem.getStartOffset(), end = elem.getEndOffset(), len = end - start;
        if (elem.isLeaf() || elem.getName().equals("html"))
            continue;
        if (start <= offset && offset < end && len <= elemLength) {
            currentElem = elem;
            elemLength = len;
        }
    }

    return currentElem;
}
```

This method is also a member of the `ModifiedHTMLDocument` class.

The solution is not pure, but it solves provisionally the problem. I hope I'll find a better kit. I'm thinking about [JWebEngine](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jwebengine). That should be replacement for current poor `HTMLEditorKit`, but I don't know, whether it allows me to add my custom tags.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps
http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html

Comment: I got started with the aid of your post. But I thing, there is nothing to be added yet. It is the solution how to load the file containing unknown tags. Do you have some expirience with inserting of custom tags after the file has been loaded? To be able to edit the hypertext, I must be able to insert my custom tag into document being already loaded in my editor pane. Unfortunately it is quite difficult.

Comment: When you insertHTML the same methods should be called. So your tag will be recognized and appropriate structures will be created.

Comment: Maybe, however the method `insertHTML()` is (in my opinion unsensually) hidden as private method. I can use only `insertBeforeStart()` and suchlike. Nevertheless when I tried, what did the `setInnerHTML()` method do, it worked only if the tag was wrapped in some non-white characters. Otherwise it didn't take any action. It appears all to be a bit funny and confused to me...