# Clickable HTML link in JEditorPane using replaceSelection method

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I searched how to make clickable links in `JEditorPane`, and I found this question:

> [Is it possible to create programs in Java that create text to link in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170041/is-it-possible-to-create-programs-in-java-that-create-text-to-link-in-chrome)

It was very useful, but my code uses a repetition statement to add links in a loop:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
jep.setContentType("text/html");
jep.setEditable(true);// Because replaceSelection can't work with disabled edit
for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ){
    jep.replaceSelection(
        "Welcome to <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>StackOverflow i </a>.");
}
jep.setEditable(false);
```

Now it shows me just text without clickable links. How am I going to make it right? I really need `replaceSelection` method.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Add the `HyperlinkListener`like suggested in the post you have linked. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing where you are stuck.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I suspect he's expecting a different result from `replaceSelection()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replaceSelection()` on an `HTMLDocument` inserts the raw string; you want to insert an HTML anchor tag. You can,

- Manage the raw HTML text yourself, a shown below, and let `setText()` handle the parsing.
- Use one of the existing [`HTMLEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) nested actions.
- Use one of the custom approaches seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7608168/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447176/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170141/230513
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }

    private static String create(int i) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Welcome to <a href=");
        sb.append("'http://www.example.com'>Example ");
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append("</a>.<br>");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void display() throws HeadlessException {
        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
        jep.setContentType("text/html");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<b>Welcome</b>:<br><hr>");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            sb.append(create(i));
        }
        sb.append("<hr>");
        jep.setText(sb.toString());
        jep.setEditable(false);
        jep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED.equals(e.getEventType())) {
                    System.out.println(e.getURL());
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    try {
                        desktop.browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame f = new JFrame("HyperlinkListener");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(jep);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i really appreciate it. Now i understand where the problem is. i tried your approach in the example and it worked perfectly