# Give JEditorPane an append(...) Method like JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

How can I use jEditorPane as jTextArea with the [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method in the jTextarea ?

example :

jTextArea.append(mystring);

jEditorPane.?

Comment: Don't use an editor pane to insert text like you do with a JTextArea. A JEditorPane should be used to insert HTML. Check out the HTMLEditorKit for method to insert HTML. Instead use a JTextPane. You can use the insertString() method and you can specify attributes as you insert text into the Document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at the [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html), specifically, the [`Document#insertString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#insertString%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) method.

With this you could could do something like...

```
Document doc = editorPane.getDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "This is the string to insert", null);
```

Comment: I've tried it that way, but the html code does not work anymore..
what should I do ?

Comment: @Arief: Update your question to include this requirement; a related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447176/230513).

Comment: You'll probably need to append the text within the content of the body of the HTML